# dhcpd hostgroup in a single file

Tags: mac, hostname, dhcpd

Is it possible to set dhcpd to read MAC addresses from file, and then to set IP and hostname for those particular hosts? To be more clear - everything is supposed to be in that file: mac, ip and hostname.
Is it possible, or I have to add manual entry for each host in dhcpd.conf?

Comment: more common would be to have a script or configuration management build the `dhcpd.conf` from your given input file

Comment: Is there an example of such script that I can use for reference?